# Regex disclude folders in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have a website with multiple subfolders (e.g. /uk/ /australia/ /canada/ etc.), and also the root website.

In Google Analytics, I would like to use Regex to filter out and disclude the subfolders so I can see the stats of the main domain pages only (without the pages from the /uk/ /australia/ /canada/ subfolders). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regexp for the pagePath to exclude all subfolders:

```
^/[^/]+$
```

To exclude specific subfolders, use this:

```
^(?!/(uk|australia|canada|etc...))/.*$
```

`(?!RE)` is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to form this.. if I want to disclude the /uk/ subfolder, it would be: ^/[uk^/]+$   ?

Comment: No. `[^listofchars]` matches a character that's not in the list of characters, and `+` means to match the previous expression 1 or more times. So `[^/]+` means a sequence of characters that don't contain `/`. That's how you filter out all subfolders.

Comment: Sorry I should mention that the root domain uses other subfolders, such as /ArticlesList/ which I would like to track, so this would filter out pages I would like to track. I just want to disclude a hand-built list, i.e. /uk/ /australia/ etc.

Comment: See the updated answer, using negative lookahead. BTW, there's no such word as "disclude", it's "exclude".